# AngularJS_UnitTesting : Expected call not been happening

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

My function to uni test

```
function get(url, headers) {
        var config =
        {
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            headers: headers
        };
        return httpHandler(config);
    }
```

test case I am writing

```
it(" When method is called with url but no header passed  \n", function () { 
            var url=baseURL + "check/HttpGET";
            httpWrapperService.get(url);
            //spy here
            expect(httpWrapperService.httpHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });

spyOn(httpWrapperService, 'httpHandler').and.callFake(function(){
               //do nothing
 });
```

I tried to put the spyOn before testing during the initializaion time, Itried to place it every where , but every time when I am running the test it says

```
" Expected spy httpHandler to have been called."
```

I am not able to figure out why it is not working .

**EDIT**

adding few more lines of code

```
beforeEach(function () {
        module("safe-repository");

        // Inject needed services
        inject(function ($scope, $httpBackend, _statusService_ , _httpWrapperService_, _settingsService_) {
            statusService=_statusService_;
            httpWrapperService=_httpWrapperService_;
            httpBackend=$httpBackend;
            settingsService=_settingsService_;
            scope=$scope;
            // Get baseUrl
            baseURL = settingsService.getServicesURL();
            // Default answer
            httpBackend.whenGET("languages/en.json").respond("OK");
            spyOn(httpWrapperService, 'httpHandler').and.callFake(function(){
               //do nothing
            });
          });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the get function is on the wrapperService, I think the problem is that you are not calling the apply function of the $scope, to "digest" the angular JS standard cycle.

Try something like this:

```
it(" When method is called with url but no header passed  \n", function () { 
        //Arrange
        var url=baseURL + "check/HttpGET";
        httpWrapperService.get(url);
        // Act
         $scope.apply();
        //Assert
        expect(httpWrapperService.httpHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
```

Comment: It says scope.apply() is not a function. where to inject it properly

Comment: are you using Jasmine testing ? you should be able to inject it as any dependency like in an Angular controller.

Comment: I have injected it , but it is giving 
 [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope error

Comment: My previous comment is wrong, have you tried to inject the rootScope ? 

  inject(function ($rootScope,